# keypress event for number in WinForm TextBox in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, keypress

I want to limit user to type just numbers in TextBox. 
I add this code In keypress Event:

```
private void txtPartID_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (((e.KeyChar >= '0') && (e.KeyChar <= '9')) == false)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

but after that BackSpace key don't work for this TextBox. How can I change this?

Answer (score 1):

You can check for backspace using this,

```
if(e.KeyChar == '\b')
```

And better way to check only for numbers is

```
private void txtPartID_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = !(Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == 8);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void TxtBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
 if (!(Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back)))

  e.Handled = true;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should handle both back key and delete key.

```
if (!(Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back)&& (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Delete)))
e.Handled = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it

```
private void txtColumn_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (((e.KeyChar >= '0') && (e.KeyChar <= '9') || (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back)) == false)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```