# WinForms textbox strange behaivor after 10 numbers

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, textbox, numeric

I'm trying to put some controls on my `TextBox` using Visual Studio 2019 WinForms.

So this is my big control

```
int myNumber;
private void txtNumberControl_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (sender != null)
        {
            myNumber = Convert.ToInt32(txtNumberControl.Text);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You can write only numbers!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
        
}
```

As you can see from the code above, I'm trying to make sure that the user inputs only numeric values. The strange behavior starts after 10 numbers writed. So if I write **12345678912** it goes in `catch` and shows me the `MessageBox` error message.

Here is a picture of it (it's in Italian but the error is the same I just translated it). 
[myErrorMessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbMnq.png)

But the most strange part is that I can put down how many `00000000000000000000000000` I want and It just works as expected.

I'm seeking for help, can someone gently explain me why is this happening?

Comment: Ask yourself: What is `Int32.MaxValue`?

Comment: Leading 0's mean nothing they don't change the value. So you can have as much as you want the value does not change. The max value an Int32 can hold is 2147483647.

Comment: While whe are at it. When you do exception handling you should show the exception and not some other text. You just hide whats happened. You would have noticed what the problem is when you have looked at the exceptions message property.

Comment: @Ralf Nice one buddy, I just realised that if I add `MessageBox.Show("Error: " + Exception)` I just says me the real reason of the error. Wow

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29092456/keypress-event-for-number-in-winform-textbox-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I would hate using this TextBox.  Any error WHILE typing would cause a message box to appear, disrupting the flow of the user.  They have to stop and read the message, then possibly switch to the mouse to dismiss the message.  Then edit the value, possibly getting another message in the process, etc...   Maybe you could provide visual feedback to the user by changing the backcolor, or like an [ErrorProvider](https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-D5nMK0eXWgg/TqHwCYeMWsI/AAAAAAAABEQ/Ru-PckIM_uQ/s1600/ErrorProviderInWinforms.PNG), or do the validation when a button is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program goes into the catch because the number you wanted to enter is now to high to be converted into an integer.

Max Value for an integer is: **`2147483647`**

You've gone over that limit with: **`12345678912`**

Because of that your program fails to convert and prints the message even tough your input is a legit number.

To actually check if the whole inputed string is a number even if it is over the integer limit. You can use [`.IsDigit()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isdigit?view=netcore-3.1) combined with [`.All()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?view=netcore-3.1) to check if any of the letters is not a number.

**Example:**

```cs
public bool CheckForNumber(string yourString) {
    // Check if all chars in this string are digits.
    if (yourString.All(char.IsDigit)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

We can now use that function in combination with the User input to check if it is a valid number.

```cs
private void txtNumberControl_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // Check the text of the object that triggered this Event.
    if (!CheckForNumber((sender as Control).Text)) {
        MessageBox.Show("You can write only numbers!", "Error", 
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return;
    }

    // Try to parse the text into a long (is 0 if the input is invalid).
    if (!long.TryParse(txtNumberControl.Text, out long number)) {
        // Not validated
    }   
}
```

Comment: Really nice answer MatthewHD, but you are missing the real reason of the error message, my integer that can store only `2147483647`. What do you suggest me to use? I need to store that value somewhere..

Comment: If the number is to big you need to either set it to the max value or make it a long instead of an integer.

Comment: Just be aware that long has a limit as well even tough it's more.

Comment: Yes, I just saw it on the wiki. That's a really big number, I don't think that my users would write down such a thing.

Comment: I would use `TryParse` btw. it makes it so if it can't be converted it instead gets the default value in this case 0, so you don't have to use try catch which is generally not a very good way to handle errors.

Comment: Yeah I saw that in your answer you didn't use try catch and I was wondering why.